# calling several matlab commands from python using os.system

Tags: python, matlab, command, os.system

I just want to call two matlab commands from Python: the fist command just adds the folder and subfolders fo the desired path (   `addpath(genpath('c:/file1/file2'))`   ), while the second command calls the function I want to use (    `myfunction.m`    ).

I always used `os.system("command")` when I needed to call a function and `os.system("command1 | command2")` when I wanted to call two functions for example, so I tried:

```
os.system("matlab -r addpath(genpath('c:/file1/file2')) | matlab -r myfunction")
```

But obviously this opens two matlab windows, the first one for the fist command and the second one for the second command. What I want is to call both commands in the same window, one after the other. However, if I try simply:

```
os.system("matlab -r addpath(genpath('c:/file1/file2')) -r myfunction")
```

it doesn't work...It performs the first command ( `addpath` ) but it does not call the function....

What I am doing wrong?? Any idea about how to do that?? I read lot of posts but they weren't very helpful, even if this is a very simple case.

Thanks in advance guys!! I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to execute the following:

```
matlab.exe -r "addpath('c:\some\folder'); someFunction(); quit;"
```

Now you have to plug that inside a `os.system` call, and properly escape quotation marks...

For example, you can try:

```
>>> os.system("matlab.exe -nosplash -nodesktop -wait -r \"addpath('c:\\some\\folder'); someFunction(); quit();\"")
```

(note that backslashes and double-quotations are escaped, plus I added the `-wait` option so that the command doesn't return until MATLAB finishes execution).

Comment: Thanks sooo much @Amro!! That works perfectly! :) It gives a matlab command window different from the normal one but this is not a problem :)

Comment: @user2252592: that's the `-nodesktop` option, you can remove it if you want. Here are the doc pages for all command line options: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html, http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabunix.html